# Android 4: starting child activity from sensor event listener: synchronizing fails

Tags: android, synchronized, android-sensors, critical-section

I'm trying to start a child activity from the sensor event listener if the smartphone is upside down. The initial code i wrote looked like this:

```
public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener{

    boolean mIsStarted = false;

    public void start(Context context) {
        mIsStarted = false;
        SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        manager.registerListener(this, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public void stop(Context context) {
        mIsStarted = false;
        SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        manager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float z = event.values[2];

            if (z < -8f) {
                if (!mIsStarted) {
                    mIsStarted = true;
                    // start child activity
                }

            } else if (z > -7f) {
                if (mIsStarted) {
                    mIsStarted = false;
                    // stop child activity
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now i have the problem, that Android 4 devices start the activity about three times instead of once. I think this happens because the onSensorChanged method is called too often in a really short time.
So i tried to synchronize it:

```
public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener{

    // ...

    public synchronized void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

That didn't work, so i tried several more approaches:

-Synchronizing the 'this' object

```
public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener{

    // ...

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        synchronized(this){
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

-Synchronizing the isStarted variable:

```
public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener{

    Boolean mIsStarted = false;

    // ...

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        synchronized(mIsStarted){
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

-Using an AtomicBoolean:

```
public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener{

    public AtomicBoolean mIsStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    // ...

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float z = event.values[2];

            if (z < -8f) {
                if (mIsStarted.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    // start child activity
                }

            } else if (z > -7f) {
                if (mIsStarted.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    // stop child activity
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

None of that approaches worked, so i wonder why this happens and how i could change it and make it work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i also tried to change the rate of the listener in this line: 
manager.registerListener(this, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
to 
manager.registerListener(this, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), 1000000);
as it says i can also enter "the desired delay between events in microsecond", so this should be a rate of one second and so enough time for the lock to work, but that didn't change anything either...

Comment: when making the isStarted variable static and using a synchronized(this), i get better results, but the error still occurs from time to time...

Answer (score 0):

in your android manifest file set attribue to activity `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

```
<activity
            android:name=".CategoryActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

I am not pretty much sure this will solve your problem but actually when sensor start your activity again as it is in signleTask it will not relaunch and activity current state remain persist.

Comment: i tried that before, but with this solution it doesn't even start the activity once... i think i'd have to stop all other activities in order to start it (so the activity with my orientation listener would also stop)

Comment: I thought you have to apply this attribute to your target activity, have to apply that to target activity?

Comment: hmm you are right, i did a mistake there, i applied it to the wrong activity, but it makes no difference to what happened before, when i apply it to the right one...

Comment: have you changed content of your target activity every time sensor changed?

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);


try this with your target activity

Comment: hmm now the target activity doesnt close again if i turn the smartphone back... i started it with: 

`mCustomActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
   startActivityForResult(mCustomActivityIntent, STARTUP_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);` 

and tried to stop it with 

`finishActivity(STARTUP_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);`